# Can I query the name of the current stylesheet in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm using matplotlib's style contexts to dynamically change my stylesheet from a dark style to a light style for printing, e.g.:

```
with plt.style.context(stylesheet, after_reset=True):
    # do plot things using new stylesheet
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to query which stylesheet is currently applied (e.g. `plt.style.get()` which doesn't exist) so I can do other things depending on whether I'm using the dark stylesheet or the light stylesheet. Any help is apprecated.

Comment: No, you will have to keep track of this yourself.

Comment: Darn, oh well. Thanks for the heads-up